# How to get access token login with webview

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, webview

I have a webview to login. After logging in with this webview, I need to capture the access token and close the webview and continue operations from mobile, how can I do this exactly?

[webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example)

Comment: The method **runJavaScriptReturningResult** in the class **WebViewController** will help you to run JavaScript code and return the result back to dart code.

Comment: Can you show a code sample how exactly you can do this?

Answer (score 0):

for your webViewController (property of WebViewWidget) set:

```
 setNavigationDelegate(    NavigationDelegate(
    onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
       String uri = Uri.parse(request.url);
       String token = uri.queryParameters['token'];
    });
```

... and retreive token from request

After that can store token, prevent webView navigation and navigate to a mob app screen